# Moving files and renameing duplicats

Tags: batch-file

I need to move files from `C:\users\users name\documents\sound recordings\` directory to our network drive `P:\transcription\users name\`. I need the files to automatically get renamed if the file exist in the `P:\transcription\users name` directory. I am a novice and can only write simple batch files and the one I wrote to move the files will over write the files with the same name in the directory. Thanks

Comment: post the one you wrote

Comment: I've posted an answer that may help you. But, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This community will not just provide answers. Please let us know what you have tried and at which part of the process you find trouble. Then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

It will display files to be moved with resulting filename. If it works ok for you , remove the line `echo !src!%%~nxa - !dst!!file!` and delete the **rem** keyword from `rem move !src!%%a !dst!!file! >nul`

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "wildcard=*.*" & rem files to search for
set "skipUsers=Guest Administrator" & rem users not to copy files

:: get users
set/a offset=0
for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%1 in ('wmic useraccount get name^,sid /format:csv') do (
  set/a offset+=1, USER_MAX=offset
  set "USER[!offset!]=%%1"
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%USER_MAX%) do (
  set/a skip=0, numFiles=0
  set "currentUser=!USER[%%i]!"
  set "src=C:\!currentUser!\documents\sound recordings\"
  set "dst=P:\transcription\!currentUser!\"

  rem get time stamp
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set "Tm=%%A"
  set "timeStamp=!Tm:~0,4!!Tm:~4,2!!Tm:~6,2!_!Tm:~8,2!!Tm:~10,2!!Tm:~12,2!"

  for %%a in (%skipUsers%) do if /I "!currentUser!" equ "%%a" set/a skip=1
  if !skip! neq 0 ( rem avoid copying blacklist users
    echo !currentUser!: Skipping
  ) else (
    <nul set/P="!currentUser!: Moving files"
    pushd !src!

    dir /ad !dst! >NUL 2>NUL || md !dst! & rem create destination folder if it doesn't exist

    for %%a in (%wildcard%) do (
      set "file=%%~nxa"
      if exist "!dst!!file!" set "file=%%~na_!timeStamp!%%~xa" & rem rem if file exist, append a time stamp suffix to avoid overwriting
      echo !src!%%~nxa - !dst!!file!
      rem move !src!%%~nxa !dst!!file! >nul
      set/a numFiles+=1
    )
    echo : !numfiles! files moved
    popd
  )
)

EndLocal
exit/B
```